# Sum two rows in one - My Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have found some similar posts, but I didn't find them useful. But I didn't know how to group them.

I would like to Sum 'No' and 'Not Set' to one row, and to lose 'Not Set' row.

So : 'No' = 'No' + 'Not Set'

I have something like this :

```
TEST           TestCount        Month
'Yes'          123              March
'No'           432              March
'Not Set'      645              March
'Yes'          13               April
'No'           42               April
'Not Set'      45               April
'Yes'          133              May
'No'           41               May
'Not Set'      35               May
....
```

And I would like something like this :

```
TEST           TestCount        Month
'Yes'          423              March      (Should be  123? - @Dems)
'No'           410              March      (Should be 1077? - @Dems)
'Yes'          154              April      (Should be   13? - @Dems)
'No'           192              April      (Should be   87? - @Dems)
'Yes'          130              May        (Should be  133? - @Dems)
'No'           149              May        (Should be   76? - @Dems)
```

....

Can anybody help me with this, tnx in advance

Comment: It's much more helpful if your example data matches your description.

Comment: @Dems Hey, You are right, I didn't explain problem properly. Will update my question as soon as posible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE test WHEN 'Not Set' THEN 'No' ELSE test END AS newtest,
        month, SUM(testCount)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        newtest, month
```

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f642/12)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN test = 'Not Set' THEN 'No' ELSE test END AS testvalue
  , SUM(testCount) as TestCount
  , month
FROM    test
GROUP BY testvalue, month
```

Comment: The fiddle returns incorrect results. Field names have a prioity over aliases in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Quassnoi its too early, I fixed it. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You could at least pick another alias! :) But +1 for the fiddle.

Comment: @Quassnoi fixed that too. :)  This is what happens when you wake up at 3am and try to answer questions

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TEST, TestCount, Month
FROM (
        (SELECT 'No' AS TEST, SUM(TestCount) AS TestCount, Month
         FROM mytable
         WHERE TEST = 'No'
           OR TEST = 'Not Set'
         GROUP BY MONTH)
      UNION
        (SELECT TEST, TestCount, Month
         FROM mytable
         WHERE TEST = 'Yes')) AS newtable
GROUP BY Month, TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TEST, TestCount, Month  
FROM   
       (SELECT 'No' AS TEST, SUM(TestCount) AS TestCount, Month  
        FROM testEntity  
        WHERE TEST = 'No' OR TEST = 'Not Set'  
        GROUP BY MONTH)  
    UNION  
       (SELECT TEST, TestCount, Month  
        FROM testEntity  
        WHERE TEST = 'Yes')  
AS newtable  
GROUP BY Month, TEST, TestCount;
```

The testCount should also be included in the Group by clause.